# Node js: association not working in sails js version 1

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, associations, one-to-one

please help me i am using Sails version 1 and i want to create association but i get error.

```
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Could not tear down the ORM hook.  Error details: Error: Invalid data store identity. No data store exist with that identity.
error: Failed to lift app: { userError: The attribute `id` on the `patients` model is an association but also specifies a type property. This is not needed and will be automatically determined.
```

So i have a 2 model (Patients and Bookings) and i want to get patient from bookings

// Patients.js

```
module.exports = {
tableName: 'patients',
primaryKey: 'id',
attributes: {
    id: {
        model: 'Bookings',
        type: 'number',
        unique: true
    }
},
```

};

// Bookings.js

```
module.exports = {
tableName: 'booking',
attributes: {
    patient: {
        collection: 'Patients',
        via: 'id'
    }
}
```

};

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the `type` property from `attributes` key in your `Patients.js` as the error suggests.

```
// Patients
module.exports = {
tableName: 'patients',
primaryKey: 'id',
attributes: {
 id: {
    type: 'number',
    unique: true
    },
 RandomAssociationName: {
    model: 'Bookings'
    }
}

// Bookings
module.exports = {
tableName: 'booking',
attributes: {
patient: {
    collection: 'Patients',
    via: 'RandomAssociationName'
  }
}
```

Comment: if i remove type key i get the another error "the type must be number or string"

Comment: why are you defining the association as the primary key ?, you can use two attributes, one as a primary key and the other reprensents the association, that way you should have no problem setting the models.

Comment: sorry @Hamza Fatmi but i dont understand what you mean when say "reprensents the association". can you send me code example or more details

Comment: @LevonBabayan In the `Patient` model, you can set up two attributes, one as the primary key of the model and the other contains the foreign key of the `Booking` model, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very match i think this way is realy working i try tommorow and write you

Comment: Hi @Hamza Fatmi sorry for late. i try this method but he return me "Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'RandomAssociationName' in 'field list'
"